# Plone 4 : How to create Multiple Plone Sites

Tags: plone, zope, buildout

I am using Plone 4 and I need to add another Plone Site in my Zope Instance i.e. One Plone site for testing/development and the other Plone site for production. I already have one Plone site installed and wonder how to install the other in the same instance.

I have followed the steps listed [here](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/multiple-plone-sites-per-zope-instance-using-separate-data-fs-files-for-each-one) but have not been successful. I am using buildout.

Could anyone tell me how to go about it or if I'm doing something wrong. Thanks.

EDIT: I am looking for a way that will result in a different Data.fs file for each Plone site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create more plone sites just go to:

```
http://<hostname>:<port>/manage
```

for example:

```
http://localhost:8080/manage
```

There you'll find a button in upper-right corner that says "Add Plone site".

Comment: Thank you. Will this result in it having a different data.fs file?

Comment: of course not. if you want a discrete Data.fs for each site that article is still good. what point of that tutorial caused you troubles?

Comment: In the final stages where I enter the Path Identifier and the Title, then click on 'Create Plone Site' I get an error. Could be my installation is corrupted. I'm looking at it again.

Comment: I discovered that my plone installation was corrupted. That is why I was unable to create it. Fixed it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To add multiple Plone sites under Zope

- Go to Zope Management Interface root: `http://localhost:8080/manage` (this is usually directly under port 8080)
- In the real ZMI Zope root you see your Plone site as one of content items
- In top right corner you should see button Add Plone Site. Press it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Will this result in it having a different data.fs file?

Comment: All the data goes to the same Data.fs by default.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set up multiple mount points within Zope. Each mount point has it's own database file. 
http://plone.org/documentation/kb/multiple-plone-sites-per-zope-instance-using-separate-data-fs-files-for-each-one

Comment: If you read my question before posting a reply, you will notice that I have already gone through this tutorial.

Comment: Saying "it doesn't work" is not enough for us to go on.  Are you following the instructions for buildout (rather than the instructions for modifying your zope.conf file directly)?  What, specifically, are you experiencing?  If you are getting any errors, please share them with us.

Comment: I discovered that my plone installation was corrupted. That is why I was unable to create it. Fixed it now. Thanks.