# Should I host multiple Plone sites in a single Zope instance?

Tags: plone, web-deployment

I’ve got a Plone site in development, and that will soon migrate to a production server, but I’m about to start work on another project in Plone. I know I could create more than one Plone site in the Zope instance (for example by following instructions linked to from [an existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298701/plone-4-how-to-create-multiple-plone-sites)), but is that the best way to host these once launched?

Is there a benefit in having each site run in a different Zope? It seems to me that the buildout configuration might get complex otherwise.

Are there downsides to one-site-per-Zope? I can already see that the resource needs might go up rather a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We *always* deploy a new Zope instance per site. Websites always change, and if you deployed multiple sites per instance, you have the following downsides:

- All the sites must follow the same software releases. You cannot upgrade a component for one site only.
- Software updates cause downtime for all sites hosted in the same instance.
- If one of the sites becomes disproportionally more popular, it'll dominate the various caches, to the detriment of the other sites. They will become disproportionally slower as their data has to be fetched from disk, always.
- You cannot simply scale up one site to meet demands without having to scale up the other sites too. Want to go from one instance to two? You'll not only need to add a load balancer, you need to add a load balancer configured to handle *all* the sites.

Unless you are hosting a series of totally uniform websites that have to move along in lock-step, there are really no upsides to hosting multiple sites in an instance.

Comment: What's the impact on resources of doing this, vs. several sites per Zope?

Comment: @IainHallam: higher memory usage, but that depends on how you've tuned your caching anyway.

Comment: I might add that the flip side of having to update all at once is that it's possible to update all at once. That's only a good strategy if the sites share a base set of add ons.

Comment: One mid-way is to create each Plone site in its own mounted ZODB storage. Then it's easy to move that storage to another Zope or ZEO instance and mount it there. http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.recipe.filestorage Caveats apply: mount it at the same path, and don't cut & paste across mounts.

Answer (score 2):

There is no single answer to this question. The answer depends on various factors like size of the individual sites, usage of the single sites etc....monitoring is your key to success...if your sites get slow then start to scale out..either with multiple app servers or moving sites with higher resource usage into their own Zope instance....as said: know what you are doing, there is no answer that applies to all setup.s